# Send message from chrome extension to chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a test app for chrome.

I also am developing an extension, which should get `tab url` and send a message to the app with the url of the tab, where the extension was activated.

In the extension I have this `background.js`

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    alert(tab.url);
});
```

the `tab.url` info is correct, I need to send to the app, (which also is in javascript).

I have read many examples on internet, but there is something I'm not getting.
How should I post the message, and how to listen on the app for that message?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external

Comment: I try this, but I dont understand. It adds the listener to the app, but I still dont know how to send the message.

Comment: Did you read the entire page? It clearly shows how.

Comment: what is an `app` exactly? Is it a web site or a chrome application (similar to an extension)?

Comment: Chrome application (similar to extension).

The application is the floating window that is runned from chrome apps

Answer (score 0):

Messaging docs [have a clear example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external).

Extension code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("appIdHere", {tabUrl: tab.url});
});
```

App code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        // Check the ID! Requests may be spoofed.
        if(sender.id == "extensionIdHere" && message.tabUrl) {
            doStuff(message.tabUrl);
        }
    }
}
```